# jQuery: Add Height from Variable

Tags: jquery, css, height

I'm trying to add height to a few elements based upon a variable. I thought this was the right approach, but it's the line breaking my javascript.

```
$('#content').css('height': '+=VariableX');
```

There seems to be so many different approaches to this, I'm not sure what's correct. I know that generally, at least for JSON, everything should have " " around it. Although I believe for primitive values, you can forego the quotes. But ultimately, I would love to be directed towards a guide that shows the best practices for the syntax here. Since clearly I've got it wrong.

Thanks.

In case my calculation is generated something incorrectly, here it is. It should generate a value that is the difference between my container height (540px) after adjustment (browser window width / 960px) less browser window height.

```
var addHeight = windowH - (540 * (windowW / (960)));
```

I've added another line of my code as I think it might be breaking as result of the way I'm ordering this zoom effect and the adding height? Maybe not though. Not sure if it matters.

```
else{

    $('#wrapper').css({'zoom': windowW / (960)});
    $('#content').css('height': '+=' VariableX);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would manage the increment outside the JQuery call:

```
var VariableX = $('#content').height();
VariableX += 1;
$('#content').height(VariableX);
```

Comment: I'm confused by your solution. I have calculated the variable, in your example equaling 1. Outside the call. It is only that one value. So I don't having var VariableX = some formula; and then variable += same formula?

Comment: Ok, if you already have the value, you can just pass it directly to the JQuery function

Comment: But I need to ADD it to existing height. What you have I am fairly certain works if VariableX = my new height, but I need to add it on. How would that syntax be formulated?

Comment: I should have perhaps stated this better. I can't actually call out the height of a specific div. As this is a dynamic value that must be injected into a number of divs (and on various pages). I need to just call this dynamic variable once and then inject where necessary.

Answer (score 1):

A line from your question:

> I know that generally, at least for JSON, everything should have " " around it.

This is Javascript, not JSON. Javascript variables should not have `""` around them, otherwise they are treated as string literals, not as variables.

What you need here is a string, part of which is formed from a variable. This involves concatenation using the `+` operator:

```
$('#content').css('height', '+=' + VariableX);
```

This builds up a string made up of `+=` followed by the contents of `VariableX`.

---

Your error has revealed the problem:

```
$('#wrapper').css({'zoom': windowW / (960)}),;
```

That last comma makes invalid Javascript. This will make your code work.

```
$('#wrapper').css({'zoom': windowW / (960)});
```

Comment: Ah okay, I didn't realize. I guess JSON and Javascript don't share that. But I've tried this and it doesn't work. I also tried it with a value as well, both with and without quotes and with and without 'px' but doesn't work. My console says syntax error.

Comment: @jstacks My best bet is that there is an error on one of the other lines of code in your JS.

Comment: Gotcha. It must be my calculation to get the variable, which I've now posted up. It doesn't break the code by itself, only when the variable is put into the jQuery call. Perhaps the value it generates breaks within your syntax. Hopefully that calculation helps.

Comment: I actually meant to edit that out. It is a syntax error even when I remove it. I put it into a javascript lint and it gives me this error for the height line: "SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list"

Comment: @jstacks I've seen what it was: you had a `:` after the first argument. You needed a `,`. Sorry for not spotting this before.